# Splice strange thing

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, arrayofarrays

I have next code

```js
function doneOrNot(board) {
    console.log(board);
    let blockNum = [...(board.splice(0, 2))];
    return blockNum;
}
console.log(doneOrNot([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]))
```

On first console.log I got

```
(3) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) [7, 8, 9]
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

(Length 3 or 1???)

And on second:

```
(2) [Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) [1, 2, 3]
1: (3) [4, 5, 6]
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

But why array of arrays have changed before (after?) split?

Answer (score 1):

[Array splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method, mutates original array and returns removed items.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
// now arr has 3 elements

const removed_items = arr.splice(0, 2);

// Now removed_items will have [1, 2]
// and arr will have [3]
```

By the time When you expand on 'console log' in dev tools, the arr has only 1 element. That is reason you are seeing the 1 element.

Comment: To add to this - if you do not want to modify the original you should use Array.slice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice